# Android - Vertical scrolling of multiple interactive items

Tags: android, android-fragments, vertical-scrolling

I want to create an interface such as the following, where each interactive object may be of different sizes, and each have its own buttons, textViews, and be fully interactive. There will be a user-defined number of these objects, and the user should be able to add these items at any time.

This is my concept art. I don't have enough rep to post pictures.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAOGx.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. and Use Listview..

this is custom listview with image and text modify it the way you want hope this helps you.
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/